# Recover database after SERVER-15369 corruption

Tags: mongodb

we have a dev database which got corrupted because of [this issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/gPjazaAePoo/SVAmv31CwDwJ). Is there any way to restore content from the database? What if I would recompile mongod such that **nsToDatabaseSubstring** always returns the result I need or it doesn't make any sense? I have had only one database.

```
2015-07-02T11:51:53.410+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.4
2015-07-02T11:51:53.410+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 0481c958daeb2969800511e7475dc66986fa9ed5
2015-07-02T11:51:53.411+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
2015-07-02T11:51:53.411+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-146-31-239 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-07-02T11:51:53.411+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-07-02T11:51:53.411+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { journal: { enabled: false } } }
[New Thread 0x7ffff4c17700 (LWP 357)]
2015-07-02T11:51:53.412+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 16777216 but mmapv1GlobalOptions.smallfiles=false: /data/db/meteor.0
2015-07-02T11:51:53.414+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure _name == nsToDatabaseSubstring( ns ) src/mongo/db/catalog/database.cpp 439
2015-07-02T11:51:53.419+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
 0xf7a0f9 0xf19121 0xefdae2 0x939df2 0x939eef 0x93be33 0x93e9a0 0x826781 0x7f2829 0x7ffff6650ead 0x823da9
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"B7A0F9"},{"b":"400000","o":"B19121"},{"b":"400000","o":"AFDAE2"},{"b":"400000","o":"539DF2"},{"b":"400000","o":"539EEF"},{"b":"400000","o":"53BE33"},{"b":"400000","o":"53E9A0"},{"b":"400000","o":"426781"},{"b":"400000","o":"3F2829"},{"b":"7FFFF6632000","o":"1EEAD"},{"b":"400000","o":"423DA9"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.0.4", "gitVersion" : "0481c958daeb2969800511e7475dc66986fa9ed5", "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.0.5-boot2docker", "version" : "#1 SMP Tue Jun 16 01:39:56 UTC 2015", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "EB7A0F7D9F202DB3ADD7637D20509D9DE82AC5A1" }, { "b" : "7FFFF7FFA000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "04D43C53E5366F8375342F884E4E2D09CD5964C0" }, { "b" : "7FFFF7BC1000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "FEF281218797AD6AE726DD5FCEDECADD9E9F51DC" }, { "b" : "7FFFF7960000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "ED2B7FC51D2E7ADD0D4F1A3667E2B6ED7257663F" }, { "b" : "7FFFF7568000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7C7F328E0814F339D251A8F8C9459E50978EC254" }, { "b" : "7FFFF7360000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F58D5DE3E7A2989E915422BA4203FE53DBA449A0" }, { "b" : "7FFFF715C000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5D1CA3A3D93ED5B6C6462FFA03E787FDBE4013A3" }, { "b" : "7FFFF6E55000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8711429397A5AF8B6269B867D830EDF6E0225B8D" }, { "b" : "7FFFF6BD3000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7F58D6664571941C86B2D969701A572AD4D7BF1D" }, { "b" : "7FFFF69BD000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F980B1188708F8D8B5C35D185444AF4CB939AA1E" }, { "b" : "7FFFF6632000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A745EBA2C16BA80AE1EF1A7A7B70740C2CF1B363" }, { "b" : "7FFFF7DDD000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9B23F2A44CC8CA6175CBD8D64584B1C7EA5FD18C" }, { "b" : "7FFFF641B000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1EFEB71FD4999C2307570D673A724EA4E1D85267" } ] }}
```

**UPD:** File was corrupted when running on DigitalOcean, so I'm not sure what virtualization software they use. I'm currently trying to run using VMWare 4.3.28 and docker. 
Basically googling pointed my to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/gPjazaAePoo/SVAmv31CwDwJ) thread, so I assume it's corrupted because of **SERVER-15369**.
We don't have older backups trough, so we have to either fix the database or re-write all the content which would take a lot of time. Unfortunately it's this way. I know importance of backing up your data, but it just happened.

**UPD 2: FIXED**
So I was able to recover the date, I run a fresh instance of mongo, copied my db files back to data folder. Then inside of mongo console I saved data on disk and shutdown the database. After I run it again I was able to see and dump my data.

Comment: How did you diagnose your database was affected by SERVER-15369? Your log output is from MongoDB 3.0.4 .. what version of MongoDB did you upgrade from, and what are your Linux kernel and VMWare versions? Recompiling MongoDB to ignore errors / return the "expected" result makes no sense if you have data corruption. Given this is a dev database I would be inclined to rebuild or restore from an older backup rather than invest a lot of time in recovery.

Comment: @Stennie posted an update to question